# binding Inner Table in RDLC Reports on the basis of Id of the outer table Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, report, datasource

I want to Bind An inner table with data, based on the Id of the Row of the outer table, Just as we do in ItemDataBound Event of Grids. The Main problem for me is that How do i pass the Id of the outer Row into a datasource and then bind that datasource to the inner table.
I am using Asp.net 4.0

Any help would be Appreciated.

[image: The format is show in the Image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then you have to use Sub reports..that sub report will contain the details of that row.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195017/SSRS-Series-Part-II-Working-with-Subreports-DrillD

Use the above link to know how to create sub reports..

Example: player details: higher level details

```
                      sub detail for each player
```

So create the sub report structure that you want for each row and embedd it in the Master report..

A parameter should be passed from main report to generate the values for sub report

Comment: well in my case i want the data to be nested inside the row of the outer table.Like we do in Nested Grids.

Comment: Please see my answer..if you do need more clarity..i will explain with an example..but sub reports are the way to go with your requirement

Comment: Please have a look at the Image i just uploaded the format of the data is shown in it.

Comment: Yes..Obviuously..You need to use sub reports..that will loop for each row of the report and renders sub report...

Comment: Send Category ID as an input to your sub report that fetches its details and display in the sub report of that row..

Comment: Actually i am very new to rdlc reports can you please show me an example or some kind of a walk through as what do i need to do in some brief details.